# Best way to filter into categories based on relative date ("today", "this week", etc.)

Tags: java, android, time, grouping

I have a list of objects (both in code and UI) that I want to filter into relative date categories such as "today" (but only in future), "this week" (but again only in future); and I also want to be able to add different types of categories (based on the object's other properties). and I've been really struggling on how to implement it, including the storage of this info.

I've been trying things like

```
groups.add(
    new Group(
        "Today", 
        Util.filterList(
            qTasks, 
            t -> LocalDate.now().isEqual(new LocalDate(t.getDueDateTime()))
        )
    ));
```

but it looks very messy, and not easy to add to in future.

What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: Today whould have the events happening between now and the end of the day? This week, would be between now and the ond of day of this weeks's Sunday?

Comment: @Juan yes, but im not looking for specific implementation, but more on how to store this information and implement it in general

Comment: For the task you could store the day as YYYYddd where YYYY is the year and ddd the number of days since january 1st. And for the week the year and the week number in the year. It should be easier to filter. Not sure if this is what your question is aiming for...

Comment: Is your question more about building an arquitechture for filtering a list by a number of dinaymc criterias (categories) for which "today" and "this week" are just examples?

Comment: @Juan Yes, something like that. I'm making a task managements app and I want to be able to have various vays of separating the list of tasks into sections, for example based on time, or which list they belong to, or tags, etc.

Comment: @davidwroxy, thank you for the clarifications. Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44269719/edit) and add the information from the comments? It will be easier to understand your requirements that way.

Comment: I don’t think there is a very intelligent way that you have not yet though about. I guess you will want to code some logic for determining whether some due time falls within one group, so it can hardly be done much more elegantly than what you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JodaTime, you could use the [Days](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html) API.  Use the Days.daysBetween(now, someDateInFuture), then compare against your selection criteria appropriately.  Or look into the [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) dateTime.isBefore(otherDateTime) api.

One example would be you have your filter selection criteria:

```
enum DurationCriteria {

    public final int dayDuration;

    DurationCriteria(int dayDuration){
       this.dayDuration = dayDuration;
    }

    DAY(1),
    WEEK(7)
}
```

Then just make the comparison based off of the DurationCriteria that is being passed to your filter:

```
DateTime endingBound = DateTime.now().plusDays(selectedCriteria.dayDuration);
if(task.getDueDate().isBefore(endingBound)){
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: what would be the best way to store this information? I want to have criteria other than time too

Comment: Eh, this answer is scoped based on duration only.  If you want to have different criteria other than time, you'd need to provide an abstract class or interface with a common interface method with different implementations.  Then just change the provided "Filter" object based on the selected filter.